# Authentication with Apple does not work for app in App store

Tags: c#, ios, .net, swift, maui

I have an application published in the App Store, when I test on the simulator during the tests, everything works for authentication with Apple, however in the app store when I download the app the authentication does not work.
I tried on another iPhone with other identifiers and the same problem

```
// Controller

[HttpPost("ValidateAppleUserAccount")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ValidateAppleUserAccount([FromForm] string id, [FromForm] string email, [FromForm] string name)
{

    var response = await _usersRepository.All.Where(x => x.IdentityId == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    UsersEntity user = new UsersEntity()
    {
        Email = email,
        ...
       
// AuthService

public async Task<AuthenticationToken> GetAuthenticationTokenApple()
{
   WebAuthenticatorResult result = null;

       string scheme = "Apple";

       if (scheme.Equals("Apple", StringComparison.Ordinal)
           && DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS
           && DeviceInfo.Version.Major >= 13)
       {
           var options = new AppleSignInAuthenticator.Options
           {
               IncludeEmailScope = true,
               IncludeFullNameScope = true,
           };
           result = await AppleSignInAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(options);
   }

   try
   {
       var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
       var jwtSecurityToken = handler.ReadJwtToken(result.IdToken);

       var email2 = jwtSecurityToken.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "email")?.Value ?? "";
       var name2 = GenerateUniqueName(email2);

       result.Properties.TryGetValue("email", out string email);
       ...

       CurrentUserId = id;

       string baseAddress = AppSettings.UrlApi;
       string apiUrlUserIdentity = $"{baseAddress}/api/v1/users/AzureId/{id}";

       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.IdToken);
       var responseUser = await client.GetAsync(apiUrlUserIdentity);

       string apiUrl = $"{baseAddress}/api/v1/users/ValidateAppleUserAccount";

       email = email2;
       name = name2;

       var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
           {
           new KeyValuePair<string, string>("id", id),
           ...
       });

       if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
       {
           var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UsersEntity>(content);
           await SecureStorage.Default.SetAsync(AppSettings.UserId, data.Id.ToString());
           return new AuthenticationToken();
```

In the database the data is recorded during authentication
I thought it could be an iPhone version problem, but in the simulator I tried an iPhone SE, and it worked too

If anyone wants to test the app: https://apps.apple.com/de/app/orbis-activities/id6464130945